# get ObjectID of top 3 viewed object mongoose

Tags: javascript, mysql, mongodb, mongoose

what i am trying to do is to obtain the ObjectId of all the documents in the db, as that is the unique identifier of 'objects' in mongoose. Here is the SQL equivalent:

`select _id from project order by viewCount desc limit 3`

**Q: what is the equivalent mongoose query?**

Is the below correct:

`ProjectModel.find({id}).sort({viewCount: -1}).limit(3).exec( 
    function(err, projects) {
        ...
    }
);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ProjectModel.find().sort({viewCount: -1}).select({_id: 1}).limit(3).exec(
    function(err, projects) {
        ...
    }
);
```

Translates to: find all docs sorted by `viewCount` descending, select the `_id` field from each doc, and limit the results to the first 3 docs.